# SSIS tabs in 'Choose Toolbox Items' missing in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I found two threads regarding this but for earlier versions of Visual Studio, with no solutions however.

I am trying to get SharePoint list destination and source into the toolbox, but I cannot even get the tabs to show.

How to get these items in there or/and show the tabs?

Windows 10, Visual Studio Data Tools 2015, fully updated

Comment: you need to add your custom component to ssis. https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/ssis/developing-a-custom-ssis-source-component/

Comment: I'm pretty sure the answer to my question does not involve coding of any kind... That link is advanced stuff - I'm asking about basic functionality.

Comment: what toolbox and what tabs do you mean? Can you give more detail because I am not sure there is a sharepoint destination in ssrs?

Comment: When you have a SSIS project active in Visual Studio and click Tools, Choose toolbox items... - you get a window with tabs, wherein two SSIS-related tabs should be available.

Comment: I can get the tabls to show, you mean the tabs like .Net Framework Componets, COM Components, etc?